# How to write a java method/algorithm to build a json tree from the flat hierarchy of parent child relationship

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph-algorithm

I am having a problem in preparing a json object using java from the below database table.

The logic is for each root_id and parent_id i am querying the db and getting the child

First query will be fired with NODE1 and NODE1 as root and parent id
The resultset will be the child ids,
Now the query will be fired again with Root ID as NODE1 and parent id as resultset for each item

DB table

| ROOT_ID | PARENT_ID | CHILD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NODE1 | NODE1 | NODE2 |
| NODE1 | NODE1 | NODE3 |
| NODE1 | NODE2 | NODE4 |
| NODE1 | NODE4 | NODE5 |
| NODE1 | NODE4 | NODE6 |

and the table goes on for node1 mostly the depth is nth level, Basically the table is representation of the below hierarchy

[image]

From the above database table i want to build the following json object

```
{
  "name": "NODE1",
  "children": [
     {
      "name": "NODE2",
      "children": [
        {
         "name": "NODE4",
         "children": [
          {
          "name": "NODE6"
           },
          {
          "name": "NODE7"
          }
        ]
       },
       {
      "name": "NODE5"
       }
     ]
    },
    {
  "name": "NODE3"
   }
  ]
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My Alogirthm is like this

Call DB to get child nodes
for each child get the sub node
repeat until we traverse all the child
some thing like this..
However, I am never able to complete the traversing

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? where is your code? Please read [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)